# Excuding the id field from the select query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, web2py

I have a table definition like the following in web2py:

```
 my_table = db.define_table('my_table',
    Field('mt_table_id', 'id', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('field_one', 'string', length=256, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('field_two', 'string', length=256, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    Field('field_three', 'string', length=256, requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
    primarykey=['my_table_id'])
```

The problem is if I execute the query:

```
results = db().select(db.my_table.my_table_id, db.my_table.field_one, db.my_table.field_two, db.my_table.field_three).as_list()
```

I get an extra field with the name `'id'` along with the field `'my_table_id'` and the other fields I have added in the select.

The SQL executed by web2py is:

```
SELECT my_table.my_table_id, my_table.field_one, my_table.field_two, my_table.field_three FROM my_table;
```

which gives the correct output.

How can I exclude this extraneous `'id'` field or at least have it removed from the output?

Comment: Thank you for both answers. I am rectifying the problem with the database.

Comment: I am rectifying the problem with the database using @anthony's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are declaring a field of type "id", then you should not also use the "primarykey" argument. The "primarykey" argument is used only if the table does not have an auto-increment integer field to serve as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I think web2py automatically add an id field to every query/table.

What you can do is either set this field to `None` but it won't remove it

```
for result in results:
    result.id = None
```

Or transform `results` as a dictionnary and remove the `id` key

```
results = results.as_dict()
for result in results
    result.pop("id", None)
```

Hope it helped and keen to know if there is a better answer :)

EDIT:
According to web2py documentation...

> Do not declare a field called "id", because one is created by web2py anyway. Every table has a field called "id" by default. It is an auto-increment integer field (starting at 1) used for cross-reference and for making every record unique, so "id" is a primary key. (Note: the id's starting at 1 is back-end specific. For example, this does not apply to the Google App Engine NoSQL.)
>
> Optionally you can define a field of type='id' and web2py will use this field as auto-increment id field. This is not recommended except when accessing legacy database tables. With some limitation, you can also use different primary keys and this is discussed in the section on "Legacy databases and keyed tables".